# Can anyone help identify this skull fragment

Tags: animal-identification

[image]

Found in the woods next to my home in central Connecticut, USA

Trying to identify, i am putting it on a shelf in my room and would like to know what it is

Comment: How long is your hand? - size will help rule out animals that are too big or too small. If you have any other photos from other angles and sides, they will help, as will other pieces of skull, skeleton and teeth. So far I would guess mammalian, with a head size around 6 in/15 cm, which could range from fox, dog, young pig or deer, large cat (probably not, these tend to be wide not long an narrow), beaver, porcupine, hare (?), armadillo.

Comment: Are there any teeth remaining in the skull? at least the upper ones. On a first look it seems to be a piglet of a wild boar

Comment: I can't say for sure, but my first thought when seeing this photo is that it is not bone, but the stalk (stipe) of a mushroom whose cap has broken off.

Comment: Could you submit a photo of the other side, and then maybe a profile?

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly confident that it is the [skull plate of a Sea Robin](https://percyulsamer.tumblr.com/post/169972461269/i-found-this-beautiful-sea-robin-skull-plate-today). This link is to fossilized collection pieces, but modern ones would be the same. Not sure how it wound up in the woods of central Connecticut, but I suppose a bird could have carried it there.

I don't have a photo of my own, but [here's another reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQicd.jpg)

Comment: "I suppose a bird could have carried it there."   The Monty Python Crew would be having such a field day with this.